# Mounting Emitter ballast resistor close to the power transistor

Tags: transistors, resistors, bjt, heat

I am helping one of my HAM radio friends to build a 25 A, 13.8 V linear reg power supply. As commonly done, I am using the parallel power transistors to deliver the current and to limit thermal runaway, using emitter ballast resisters. Now the power transistors are mounted on a separate fan cooled heat sink block and I plan to put 0R1 3W SMD ballast resistors on my PCB. My friend is adamant that these have to be like wirewound type and mounted near the transistors. I can't think of any good reason to cook the resistors near the power transistor, apart maybe if we use positive temp co. resisters. Why should we use wirewound type and mount them near the power transistor?

Comment: It saves space, perhaps? Wirewound resistors are pretty resilient to overheating, so I wouldn't be worried about them getting hot. They do also have a positive temperature coefficient like most resistors, but it's fairly small. I'm more concerned by the fact that you're trying to make a 25 amp *linear* power supply; is your load that noise-sensitive that you can't even do a switching preregulator?

Comment: Wirewound ***do*** have a positive tempco, circa 3300-4000 ppm/K. (Never know what kind of copper you are getting.) Let's say you are dividing the current up 5-ways, or 5 A per ballast. Then the ballast exhibits about +2 mV/K. And this just about matches the typical value of -2 mV/K for BJT emitters. I've not spent time worrying about this, though. Just noting it. You get to worry about it. Another reason is that wire-wound are very tolerant of high inrush currents, which this power supply may experience. Just one more thought.

Comment: @Hearth. The ham guys are wary of switchers as some of their gear is working at AM frequencies under 2MHz, just where you’d get artifacts of the switching freq. i dare say an off the shelf switcher properly filtered would do the job though. The old big transformer and a string of 2N3055s from the 70’s lives on. Probably still uses a uA723.....

Comment: If you put the drivers for the power transistors as well as the ballast resistors on the heatsink, then everything else on your control board is very low power and will run cool. One fewer things to think about cooling.

Comment: Thanks Hearth, yeah when I looked into temp co, it was very small, so that logic is marginal I think at best. 
Thanks Kartman, yes you are spot-on. My ham friend has tried switched mode and he cant use some bandwidths at all. I havent looked into the SMPS he tried, so there may have been some improvements that could have been done.
Yeah the design uses the ever famous uA723 :D long lived IC that one.

Comment: Thanks jonk, Yes I looked into couple of wirewounds and the temp co was small. I also couldn't put too much weight onto this argument but that was the only one I could think why you want to put the ballasts near the power transistor. 
Thanks for the in-rush current info. Yes that sounds like a good reason.

Comment: Thanks Neil_UK. Yeah that is another good argument of separating the ballast resisters from the PCB. Once the PCB is made, I will share further test details here for anyone to have a look.

Comment: Less wires to connect!

Answer (score 0):

In a related context (Class-AB push pull amplifier) I've noticed that the inductance of wirewound emitter resistors can be a problem and make the whole thing unstable or even oscillate. Likewise for long wires. No problem at all with SMD resistors. I used a bunch of 1R SMD resistors, if the PCB is vertical they get good airflow. If they are on the back side of the board, they can be coupled to the heatsink with squishy thermal interface material.

So in your case, why not make a small PCB attached to the heatsink, carrying both the transistors and the SMD resistors? Then you only connect this to the main board with three wires, instead of three wires per transistor. It is also much more stable mechanically, because attaching wires to transistor leads is cumbersome.

In fact, since these power transistors will need a driver, in the end it would probably be much simpler to just attach the whole pcb to the heat sink, leaving out just the huge smoothing caps.

Comment: Thanks bobflux. Yes I can do a small PCB as you suggest. So what we are trying to achieve is then to remove the heat generating ballast resistors from the main PCB, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, usually there is a sweet spot for SMD resistor price vs value vs power, if you want 0R1 3W it will most likely be cheaper to use 10x 1R 0.5W resistors in parallel. Not difficult to solder either, and has more surface area, so in the end better dissipation. If the heat sink is vertical, the small pcb will be vertical, so the resistors get much better airflow than on horizontal pcb.

Comment: And if you put the resistors on the heat sink side and fasten the pcb with screws, you can dump the heat from the resistors in the heat sink with 3mm thick [squishy thermal pads](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32988894487.html). I was suggesting to put the whole PCB on the heat sink, because that way there are less wires and less headaches. Also you can use a SMD temperature probe to control your fan, or thermal cutoff, all self contained.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal runaway can be managed simply by providing adequate voltage drop across the ballast resistors, meaning proximity isn't important. True, one could use a positive temp co resistor to get away with a slightly smaller value resistor, improving efficiency, but this is typically a marginal improvement. If you have very low headroom (Vin-Vout less than 1V) and are very concerned about efficiency then possibly this would be a good idea.

Wirewound resistors will have a lot of stray inductance which is undesirable. This inductance might affect loop response meaning an undesirable dynamic response to line or load changes, even stability issues.  The inductance could possibly cause inductive kick voltage spikes when load current abruptly drops.

Absent a specific design objective to support proximal resistors then I'd go with whatever is easier to construct, and I'd avoid wire wound resistors (again, unless there's a specific reason otherwise).

Good luck, it sounds like a fun project!

Comment: Thanks 65Roadster, Yes I check the temp co of some wire wound resistors and it was marginal. Yeah I totally agree with you, unless we have a definite advantage the wire would would provide over SMD, I would stay with SMD.